# I keep receiving a unexpected token, expected ; (1,7)

Tags: java

I am following a YouTube tutorial and I keep receiving this error.

```
public class Java_lesson_1
{
  public static void main(string[]arguments)
  {
    system.out.println("hello world")
  }
}
```

The reported error is:

> Native Browser JavaScript
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (1:7)

[image: The reported error]

Answered!!

Comment: Java is not JavaScript. Your code is Java.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thx appreciate the correction!! :)

Comment: Don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: @Pshemo my account is to new it says im not allowed to do that yet, Im sorry!!

Comment: First, always post your code directly -- do not use images. Second, what IDE are you using?  The mix of Java and the error for JavaScript is confusing.

Comment: I am using the IDE relp.it the reason is due to me being on chrome OS i cants use Linux files and such.

Comment: never mind found the issue it was the IDE not the code the Ide had its own way of introducing the file name do to it being browser based.

Comment: Are you sure? Account age doesn't affect anything. It is account *reputation points* which decide what you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. New accounts (with 1 reputation point) can't post *images*, and it is *precisely* to make question author post code/error as text (images can't be copied into IDE, nor their content can be used by search engines).

Comment: @Pshemo Yes this is my second day and i only have one rep point so those constrictions apply to my acc.

Comment: My point was this limitation isn't because of account *age*, but its *reputation points* (those can be related but are not the same). Anyway it looks like repl.it at start is asking you to select language for project. Based on `Native Browser JavaScript` in error message it may look like you selected JavaScript instead of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed putting `;` at the end of line 5:

```
System.out.println("hello world");
```

Edited:

Use `public` instead of `Public` and `System` instead of `system`:

```
public class Java_Lesson_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: I added and removed it no matter what i still receive the same error.

Comment: @HamzaNabih Can you post your code here instead of an image?

Comment: @HamzaNabih Did you save file after modifying it? If not you would still compile old version of file with problem which you attempted to fix.

Comment: Public class Java_Lesson_1
{
      public static void main(String[] arguments)
{
      system.out.println("hello world");

   }
}

Comment: @HamzaNabih I think you are compiling the old code as mentioned by Pshemo

Comment: The IDE i use every time i run it the code automatically is refreshed

Comment: @suvojit_007 nope i tried it just know still yet to work.

Comment: @HamzaNabih just check the above code again. You should have used **System** instead of system and **public** instead of Public.

Comment: @suvojit_007 fixed both of those things

Comment: @HamzaNabih is it working properly now? If no then make sure your java file name is same as your public class name

Comment: @suvojit_007 ill do that rn

Answer (score 0):

Mistake 1: `s in String should be CAPITAL`

Mistake 2: `First s in System should be CAPITAL`

Mistake 3: `In Java every statement ends with a ;`

Below is the correct code. Remember Java is a case-sensitive language. String and string aren't same.

```
public class Java_Lesson_1
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.